# How export my users from a linux with apache server to Firebase Google

Tags: android, apache, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm New using Firebase Google. I want to send push messages. But I only want to send this message to some users that are in my debían with apache server.
So how I connect both?
And how send the push messages to some users that have a specific value in the DB?

For example if I want to send the push message only to the users that have more than 30 years.

I Hope you could help me or show me some examples.

Comment: How does the image help with your question?

Comment: I just put the image to show that i am using google firebase